# How do I encode videos into h.264 at 8k resolution?

Tags: premiere, adobe, h.264, avchd

I am trying to use premiere, but I wouldn't mind switching computer programs to accomplish my goal. h.264 is an amazing codec for exporting videos, it is the fastest I've seen yet. Same exact videos but in a different codec take 5-10 times as long to export. So I'd like to make videos with the h.264 codec.

Anyway adobe premiere only supports up to 4k when it comes to outputting with h.264, and that is because at the time, h.264 only contained max with of 4096 pixels or something.

Now, there is h.264 "advanced video coding", and I have videos on my computer, that are 8k, and are in this h.264 avc codec.

My question is, how do I convert to, or export in, a 264 video.

If I can't do this with premiere, can someone point me to a program that does it? I would be able to take a 4k video, with 8k esque bitrate, convert it to a 8k video, and it would look some what decent.

I know this isn't optimal, but please help me figure out some way to upscale into this 8k avc format.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure the 8k videos on your computer are actually h.264, and not h.265?  The max resolution of h.264 level 5.2 is [still 4096x2305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC).  To convert beyond that in Premiere, you need to chose HEVC (h.265) as the format in the export settings dialog.  The HEVC stands for High Efficiency Video Coding, and you might have that confused with "advanced video encoding."  H.265 supports up to 8192×4320.  Upscaling your 4k in Premiere shouldn't be a problem, either.  I'd do it by changing the project settings to my desired resolution, then scaling the timeline video to fit, but you could probably also do it in the export settings dialog.

Answer (score 4):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) can use x264 to output to 8K.

Basic template:

```
ffmpeg -i 4KfromPremiere.mp4 -vf scale=7680x4320 -crf 20 out.mp4
```

Comment: Have you tried this? As per Jason Conrad's answer, I thought h264 had an aspect size limit. Not at a workstation w/ffmpeg to test this right now.

Comment: H.264 has no size limit. What it has is levels, where a level specifies a max resolution allowed, among other things. Those levels are for the benefit of players (esp. H/W players) so that they can gracefully decline to play a file beyond their capabilities, rather than stutter and provide a bad experience. But the bitstream syntax itself ha no upper limit and the x264 encoder doesn't, either. x264 will complain about the limits being breached, during processing, but encode anyway. Legally speaking (in tech sense), the output is not spec-complaint but software players will play it.

Comment: Other encoders, like Mainconcept, apparently refuse to encode a file which can't legally satisfy any level constraints. This looks to be the source of the belief that H.264 has a maximum resolution limit.

Comment: thanks - always a pleasure to read your very informative posts!